# Right design to expose a distributed cache to upstream services

Tags: java, caching

I am working a cache, which stores status of a particular object. This status is required by number a number of upstream services. The cache has following SLA requirements.

1. Latency : 50 ms
2. Rps : 500,000
3. Availability: 99.99
4. Consistency: Eventual consistency is acceptable.

Updates to cache are pushed by downstream Kafka consumer's whenever data changes.

If I layer the cache, with a service on to top simply to be expose rest api, the service becomes a single point of failure as I need to scale it on demand. Also, the service has to connect to the cache which would add additional latency.

What is the right way to expose the cache? Should I add an additional layer on top of the cache or should I directly expose the cache to upstream services? I am doing access control with the AWS IAM role so that upstream services can only fetch the data from cache. Is this a good design?

Comment: What API does the "raw" cache have right now? Are the upstream services Java only?

Comment: Yes, upstream services are java only.

Comment: Then I would access the cache without intermediate service layer. In case I want to present a simpler interface then the cache API to developers of upstream services, this can be solved with a interface library.